# NSBezierPath AddClip to mask NSImage - Size issue

Tags: macos, cocoa, mask, nsimage, nsbezierpath

On a macOS (OSX) desktop app, I use NSBezierPath to draw a random closed shape which looks like this.

[image]

As you can see the dashed line shows the closed path which was drawn.

Now am trying to extract the masked image as per this path.
But i get a small portion of the image.  The masked image seems to correctly get the outline from the BezierPath.  But size is an issue.

[image]

This is the method which returns the masked/clipped image.
The sourceImage.size for this drawing - 1021 * 1031

```
  - (NSImage *)imageByApplyingClippingBezierPath:(NSImage *)sourceImage
                                bezierPath:(NSBezierPath *)bezierPath
                                  newFrame:(NSRect)newFrame
  {
    NSImage* newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:newFrame.size];
    NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc]
                             initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL
                             pixelsWide:newFrame.size.width
                             pixelsHigh:newFrame.size.height
                             bitsPerSample:8
                             samplesPerPixel:4
                             hasAlpha:YES
                             isPlanar:NO
                             colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                             bytesPerRow:0
                             bitsPerPixel:0];

    [newImage addRepresentation:rep];

    [newImage lockFocus];

    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    [bezierPath addClip];

    NSRect targetFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, newFrame.size.width, newFrame.size.height);
    [sourceImage drawInRect:targetFrame];

    [newImage unlockFocus];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    return newImage;
}
```

How can i get perfectly sized image outlined by the BezierPath?
Any tips would be appreciated!

### UPDATE

Just clarifying, how i draw the image.
I get rectangle bounds of the bezier path and rectangular image cropped  like this.

```
CGRect bezierBounds = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox([self.smartLassoWavyBezierPath quartzPath]);
 NSRect targetFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, bezierBounds.size.width, bezierBounds.size.height);
 NSImage *targetImage = [[NSImage alloc initWithSize:targetFrame.size];
[targetImage lockFocus];
[self.view.originalLoadImageOnCanvas 
drawInRect:targetFrame fromRect:bezierBounds operation:NSCompositeCopy 
 fraction:1.0f];
[targetImage unlockFocus];
```

Comment: How do you draw the image?

Comment: @Willeke I updated the answer - to show you code.  I get the rectangular image cropped from the BezierPath's bounds.   Then i send this rectangular image to the 'imageByApplyingClippingBezierPath' function.

Comment: How do you draw the image to draw on? Is it scaled?

Comment: @Willeke - am not sure what you mean?  Can u be specific?

Comment: When you draw the path on an image, how do you display this image? I mean the first image in the question with the buildings. It looks like the image on screen is scaled at 40% and the mask at 100%.

Comment: @Willeke  Thanks for your patience.
I draw a path on the image using Stroke method of NSBezierPath ....
Then i get the rectangular bounds of the path using - CGPathGetPathBoundingBox .....
Then i crop/extract the rectangular image based on the bounds from the original image ...... (see code snippet on UPDATE)......
If i show this cropped image is shown on NSImageView, i get the correct rectangular crop of the image as per the Bezier Path.....
But i dont need rectangular crop, i need masked image outlined to the BezierPath.  Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: If you draw the lasso near the edges of the image, are `bezierBounds.size` and the original image size almost the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176713/discussion-between-kamyfc-and-willeke).

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5;

```
func imageByApplyingClippingBezierPath(source: NSImage, path: NSBezierPath, frame: NSRect) -> NSImage? {
    let new = NSImage(size: frame.size)
    guard let rep = NSBitmapImageRep(bitmapDataPlanes: nil, pixelsWide: Int(frame.size.width), pixelsHigh: Int(frame.size.height), bitsPerSample: 8, samplesPerPixel: 4, hasAlpha: true, isPlanar: false, colorSpaceName: NSColorSpaceName.calibratedRGB, bitmapFormat: .alphaFirst, bytesPerRow: 0, bitsPerPixel: 0) else { return nil}

    new.addRepresentation(rep)
    new.lockFocus()

    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext
    context?.saveGState()
    path.addClip()

    let targetFrame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(frame.size.width), height: Int(frame.size.height))

    source.draw(in: targetFrame)
    new.unlockFocus()
    context?.restoreGState()

    return new
}
```